# Node is non blocking. Then why is async keyword used

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Whenever i use await. I need to mark the function as async (non blocking). Isn't node by default async? What significance this keep words add.

Comment: see eg https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-promises-and-why-async-await-wins-the-battle-4fc9d15d509f

Answer (score 0):

Node is not by default async. Node favors asynchronous APIs because it is single-threaded. You may write synchronous code. It depends on APIs and modules you are using, not on node itself.

Answer (score 0):

From nodejs.org blog https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/how-to-write-asynchronous-code/

> Node.js promotes an asynchronous coding style from the ground up, in
>   contrast to many of the most popular web frameworks.

So while node.js suggests async coding, it is still JavaScript, and Javascript does not do async unless you tell it to, through callbacks, promisify, or async/await.